# Preventing heat damage when soldering a BGA

Tags: soldering, heat-protection

What are ways to prevent heat damage to a BGA chip on a small (~7mm by 17mm) PCB?

Most practices only uses heat sink but due to the size of the board it would be difficult.  Is there any other way to protect the chip IOs?

Comment: A BGA chip will have a defined heating profile for soldering in its data sheet. Follow that heating profile. Unless you mean during use, in which case control the ambient temperature during use.

Comment: Heat plates for soldering work quite well with BGAs but, as Neil stated already, you should always follow manufacturer's heat profile recommendations.

Comment: Vapor Phase Reflow (google it). But this is generally not for hobbyists. Although there is one guy on Youtube that has a home Vapor Phase setup.

Comment: Are you asking about heat during operation, or heating of the device during attachment (soldering) to the board?

Comment: And I don't understand the reference to the chip IOs.  Could you please clarify?

Comment: I meant the heat during soldering, and I mentioned the IOs because the heat will directly affect the chip IOs as there is noting to the path from the soldering point to the chip pads.

Comment: @Shannon - Thanks for that clarification.  How were you planning on soldering the BGA to the board?  Using a soldering iron with a fine tip to heat the attachment via from the back side of the board and try to melt the solder paste?

Comment: Solder reflow is the way I've seen BGA attachment done.  A solder paste is applied to the pads, then the BGA is placed down.  The entire PCB is run through a reflow oven that heats the entire board to the point where the solder paste melts and forms the connection between the ball and the pad.  During this operation, which has very well defined and control heating and cool down profiles, the BGA is heated to approximately 240 deg C.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a temperature controlled hot-air machine or reflow oven to solder it.  By staying within the specified temperature curve, you don't cause heat damage.